# Cholesky versus eigendecomposition for drawing samples from a multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, random-generation, svd, cholesky-decomposition

I would like to draw a sample $\mathbf{x}  \sim N\left(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{\Sigma} \right)$. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Drawing_values_from_the_distribution) suggests either using a [Cholesky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition) or [Eigendecomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix), i.e.
$
\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{D}_1\mathbf{D}_1^T
$
or
$
\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{Q}\mathbf{\Lambda}\mathbf{Q}^T
$

And hence the sample can be drawn via:
$
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{D}_1 \mathbf{v}
$
or 
$
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{Q}\sqrt{\mathbf{\Lambda}} \mathbf{v}
$
where 
$
\mathbf{v} \sim N\left(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{I} \right)
$

Wikipedia suggests that they are both equally good for generating samples, but the Cholesky method has the faster computation time.  Is this true?  Especially numerically when using a monte-carlo method, where the variances along the diagonals may differ by several orders of magnitude?  Is there any formal analysis on this problem?

Comment: Damien, the best recipe to make sure what program is faster is to check it yourself on your software: Cholesky- and Eigen- decompositions functions may vary in speed in different implementations. The Cholesky way is more popular, AFAIK, but the eigen way may be potentially more flexible.

Comment: I understand Cholesky to be faster $O(N^3/3)$ ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition#Computation)) whereas eigendecomposition is $O(N^3)$ ([Jacobi Eigenvalue Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalue_algorithm#Iterative_algorithms).  However, I have two further problems: (1) What does "potentially more flexible" mean? and (2) The variances differ by several orders of magnitude ($10^{-4}$ vs $10^{-9}$ for the most extreme elements) - does this have a bearing on the selected algorithm?

Comment: @Damien one aspect of "more flexible" is that the eigendecomposition, which for a covariance matrix corresponds to the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition), can be truncated to get an optimal low-rank approximation of the full matrix. The truncated SVD can be computed directly, rather than computing the full thing and then throwing out the small eigenvalues.

Comment: How about reading [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40316331/4891738) at Stack Overflow: [Obtain vertices of the ellipse on an ellipse covariance plot (created by `car::ellipse`)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40316331/4891738). Although the question is asked in different application, the theory behind is the same. You will see nice figures for geometric explanation there.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem was studied by by [Straka et.al](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/xpls/abs_all.jsp?arnumber=6580303) for the [Unscented Kalman Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Unscented_Kalman_filter) which draws (deterministic) samples from a multivariate Normal distribution as part of the algorithm.  With some luck, the results might be applicable to the monte-carlo problem.

The Cholesky Decomposition (CD) and the Eigen Decomposition (ED) - and for that matter the actual [Matrix Square Root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix) (MSR) are all ways in which a positive semi-definite matrix (PSD) can be broken down.

Consider the [SVD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition) of a PSD matrix, $P = USV^T$.  Since P is PSD, this is actually the same as the ED with $P = USU^T$.   Moreover, we can split the diagonal matrix by its square root: $P = U\sqrt{S}\sqrt{S}^TU^T$, noting that $\sqrt{S} = \sqrt{S}^T$.

We may now introduce an arbitrary orthogonal matrix $O$:

$P = U\sqrt{S}OO^T\sqrt{S}^TU^T = (U\sqrt{S}O)(U\sqrt{S}O)^T$.

The choice of $O$ actually affects the estimation performance, especially when there is strong off-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix.

The paper studied three choices of $O$:

- $O = I$, which corresponds to the ED;
- $O = Q$ from the [QR decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition) of $U\sqrt{S} = QR$, which corresponds to the CD; and
- $O = U^T$ which leads to a symmetric matrix (i.e. MSR)

From which the following conclusions were drawn in the paper after much analysis (quoting):

> - For a to-be-transformed random variable with uncorrelated elements all the three considered MDs provide identical sigma points and hence
>     they make almost no difference on quality of the [Unscented Transform] approximation. In
>     such a case the CD may be preferred for its low costs.
> - If the random variable contains correlated elements, the use of different [decompositions] may significantly affect quality of the [Unscented Transform] approximation
>     of the mean or covariance matrix of the transformed random variable.
>     The two cases above showed that the [ED] should be preferred.
> - If the elements of the to-be-transformed variable exhibit strong correlation so that the corresponding covariance matrix is nearly
>     singular, another issue must be taken into account, which is numerical
>     stability of the algorithm computing the MD. The SVD is much more
>     numerically stable for nearly singular covariance matrices than the
>     ChD.

**Reference:**

- Straka, O.; Dunik, J.; Simandl, M. & Havlik, J. "Aspects and comparison of matrix decompositions in unscented Kalman filter", American Control Conference (ACC), 2013, 2013, 3075-3080.

Answer (score 8):

Here is a simple illustration using R to compare the computation time of the two method.

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(clusterGeneration)
set.seed(1234)
mean <- rnorm(1000, 0, 1)
sigma <- genPositiveDefMat(1000)
sigma <- sigma$Sigma

eigen.time <- system.time(
  rmvnorm(n=1000, mean=mean, sigma = sigma, method = "eigen")
  )

chol.time <- system.time(
  rmvnorm(n=1000, mean=mean, sigma = sigma, method = "chol")
  )
```

The running times are

```
> eigen.time
   user  system elapsed 
   5.16    0.06    5.33 
> chol.time
   user  system elapsed 
   1.74    0.15    1.90
```

When increasing the sample size to 10000, the running times are

```
> eigen.time <- system.time(
+   rmvnorm(n=10000, mean=mean, sigma = sigma, method = "eigen")
+   )
> 
> chol.time <- system.time(
+   rmvnorm(n=10000, mean=mean, sigma = sigma, method = "chol")
+   )
> eigen.time
   user  system elapsed 
   15.74    0.28   16.19 
> chol.time
   user  system elapsed 
   11.61    0.19   11.89
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the manual, or poor-man's, prove-it-to-myself demonstration:

```
> set.seed(0)
> # The correlation matrix
> corr_matrix = matrix(cbind(1, .80, .2, .80, 1, .7, .2, .7, 1), nrow=3)
> nvar = 3 # Three columns of correlated data points
> nobs = 1e6 # One million observations for each column
> std_norm = matrix(rnorm(nvar * nobs),nrow=nobs, ncol=nvar) # N(0,1)
```

$$\text{Corr}=\small \begin{bmatrix}
1 & .8 & .2\\
.8& 1 & .7 \\
.2&.7&1
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$\text{N}=\tiny \begin{bmatrix}
&       [,1]   &    [,2]    &   [,3] \\
[1,] & -1.0806338  &  0.6563913 & 0.8400443 \\
[2,] & -1.1434241  & -0.1729738 & -0.9884772 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
 [999999,] & 0.4861827 & 0.03563006 & -2.1176976 \\
[1000000,] & -0.4394551 & 1.69265517 & -1.9534729\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

**1. SVD METHOD:**

$$\left[ \bf \underset{[3 \times 3]}{\color{blue}{\Large\,U}}\,\,\,\,\,\underset{\tiny \begin{bmatrix}\sqrt{d_1}&0&0\\0&\sqrt{d_2}&0\\0&0&\sqrt{d_3}\end{bmatrix}}{\Large\color{blue}{\Sigma^{0.5}}} \, \underset{[3\times 10^6]}{\Large\color{blue}{N^T}} \right]^T$$

```
> ptm <- proc.time()
> # Singular Value Decomposition method:
> svd = svd(corr_matrix)   
> rand_data_svd = t(svd$u %*% (diag(3) * sqrt(svd$d)) %*% t(std_norm))
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   0.29    0.05    0.34 
> 
> ptm <- proc.time()
```

**2. CHOLESKY METHOD:**

$$\bf \left[ \underset{\begin{bmatrix}c_{11}&0&0\\c_{21}&c_{22}&0\\c_{31}&c_{32}&c_{33}\end{bmatrix}}{\Large\color{blue}{\text{Ch}}}\,\,\underset{[3\times 10^6]}{\Large\color{blue}{N^T}} \right]^T$$

```
> # Cholesky method:
> chole = t(chol(corr_matrix))
> rand_data_chole = t(chole %*% t(std_norm))
> proc.time() - ptm
   user  system elapsed 
   0.25    0.03    0.31
```

---

Thank you to @userr11852 for pointing out to me that there is a better way to calculate the difference in performance between SVD and Cholesky, in favor of the latter, using the function [`microbenchmark`](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-the-microbenchmark-package-to-compare-the-execution-time-of-r-expressions/). At his suggestion, here is the result:

```
microbenchmark(chol(corr_matrix), svd(corr_matrix))
Unit: microseconds
              expr     min     lq      mean  median      uq     max neval cld
 chol(corr_matrix)  24.104  25.05  28.74036  25.995  26.467  95.469   100  a 
  svd(corr_matrix) 108.701 110.12 116.27794 111.065 112.719 223.074   100   b
```

Comment: @user11852 Thank you. I read cursorily the entry on `microbenchmark` and it really makes a difference.

Comment: Sure, but does it have a difference in estimation performance?

Comment: Good point. I haven't had time to explore the package.